# como mostrar video loop em videoview no android studio

Tags: android, android-activity

Tenho uma videoview na minha aplicação android e o vídeo de fundo está definido dessa maneira

```
String uri = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.oceans;
 VideoView mVideoView  = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_login);
 if (mVideoView != null)
 {  mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uri));
     mVideoView.requestFocus();
     mVideoView.start();
 }
```

como posso fazer esse video ser mostrado em loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o video for definido dentro da activity, o seguinte trecho de codigo funciona:

```
mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.setLooping(true);
            }
        });
```